# ListView Data Virtualization concepts and implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, virtualization, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to get a simple ListView to perform while potentially loading thousands of items. It seems that the best way to accomplish this is using Virtualization - specifically data virtualization. But I cannot get it to work, or I'm just simply misunderstanding the concepts.

I have a simple repository, returning POCO classes like this from Sqlite:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAllAsync(Action<T> predicate);
```

Then in XAML I have something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="VirtualisedMetroListView" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListView}" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
</Style>
```

Which the ListView uses. Now I don't really know anything about the "VirtualizingStackPanel" or MahApps "VirtualisedMetroListView" because, especially for the latter, there is very little documentation. But the above construct seems to work for some ppl?

Anyways, this does not work for me, and frankly I don't understand why it should! Isn't data virtualization supposed to only fetch what is visible (requested) from the ListView? But how would that ever work for my Repository above? It always returns all items of T. Not just the 20 visible in the list.

Does anyone have some links to working example of this? Or perhaps the patience to explain the concept to me :)

Thanks.

Comment: Virtualization doesn't mean it will fetch only data what is visible.  It will always fetch all data.  Virtualization means that the control will create visual elements (content) only for the items visible on screen at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, that was my understanding also. But I was confused about some sites talking differently about UI vs Data virtualization. And just had to be sure that there weren't any magic happening in the Data Virtualization concepts that I should be using...

Answer (score 1):

The virtualising panels are about UI virtualisation rather than data virtualisation.

UI experts recommend showing a user a maximum of roughly 200 rows. Any more and you should be filtering so the user doesn't have to scroll and scroll and scroll.... to find the one row they're looking for.

As it is, I suggest you use skip and take in your linq. Either add another method which does this internally in your repository or expose iqueryable rather than ienumerable.
You can then loop in an async method.
Get the first 100 records using an async call.
Translate to viewmodels.
Return that to the ui thread.
Foreach, sdd to your bound observablecollection.
Free up the ui thread by await task.Delay(500) or something.
And... keep on skipping and taking until you have all your data.

If you sort these in the order they usually want to work with them then you could implement user paging. Get the first screen full's worth with take(50) and then allow them to "page" through by clicking a next button.  Or make an itemscontrol of page buttons allow them to page anywhere in the list.

Comment: Good and important point from the UI experts...seems like the correct way to handle this. But continuing the idea - the Skip/Take stuff would have to work on the entire dataset right? Meaning that all 100K rows are actually pulled from the database? There is no magic turning "select * from whatever" into lazy loading in the SQL server...?

Comment: No. Linq skip take translates to sql offset and fetch. In sql server anyhow. Not sure about sqllite.

Comment: But only for tools like Linq2Sql et al, that builds the SQL. If you have predefined SQL in either stored procedures or inline SQL it won't. Linq as such only operates on IEnumerable and such.

Comment: You can parameterise the number for offset in a stored procedure or piece of sql.

Comment: Yes thanks - but it is a very important detail :). I think the correct answer to this question is your second paragraph, i.e. don't load that much data into the UI. Now if only MS didn't "ditch" Linq2Sql...

Comment: What's the problem with ef6 or core? If, for whatever reason, you couldn't use fetch then you could consider de-normalising. Add a pages table which holds page number and row id and re-calculate overnight. Or even serialise pages of data into separate files. Serialisation is lightning fast on load up compared to a local db.